# Issue while Updating drools version from 7.44.0.Final to 7.64.0.Final

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am currently working on updating drools version from 7.44.0.Final to 7.64.0.Final.

We have some customOperators defined extending `BaseEvaluator`. I face an issue where a call to `fireAllRules()` ends up in the following method of **EvaluatorWrapper.class** file: `public void loadHandles(InternalFactHandle[] handles, InternalFactHandle rightHandle)` which in turn calls `private static InternalFactHandle getFactHandle(Declaration declaration, InternalFactHandle[] handles)`.

This `getFactHandles()` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am expecting 2 entries in `handles[]` array but it shows just 1 due to which we get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

It is suspected that the issue could be due to the following change made in drools version 7.52.0 as detailed out here:

https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.57.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#optimize-query-payload

While analyzing further, I updated my drools version to 7.49.0.Final and here it works successfully and the flow does not go to the `public void loadHandles(InternalFactHandle[] handles, InternalFactHandle rightHandle)` & `private static InternalFactHandle getFactHandle(Declaration declaration, InternalFactHandle[] handles)` in the EvaluatorWrapper.class file.

Here is the **Sample DRL**... Problem is with the `evaluateRight` of the Custom Operation.

```
import java.util.Date;
...
...
dialect \"mvel\"

rule \"update\"

when
$en : Fact(path == \"Encounter\" )
$a : Fact(path == \"Account\" , (($en.getElement(\"subject\") referenceMatch 
this.getElement(\"subject\"))))
then
....
end
```

Kindly let me know if anyone is aware of or has faced similar issues while updating the drools version.

Comment: So you just want to know if people have seen this, not how to deal with it? Not sure how useful that is as a Q&A.

Comment: That being said, starting in a recent version of Drools (somewhere around 7.45), they no longer guarantee that minor version bumps won't contain breaking changes, so it's likely that you've run into one here and simply need to update your code to deal with the new reality.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , Yes I want to know how to solve this.                                      Does it mean that the latest version should have solved the issue and hence we should take the major updates? As in, update from 7.44.0.Final to 7.8X.x since both 7.5X.x and 7.6X.x have the same problem?

Comment: I also tried with drools version 7.66.0.Final which is the latest version available and I still face the same issue.
Can anyone provide the fix for this?

Comment: "7.5X", "7.6X" ... these are not major updates per semver, they're minor version increments. With drools all updates are now "major" updates -- semver no longer applies.  Backwards compatibility and non-breaking changes are no longer guaranteed. No matter what version bump you do, you now need to read the release notes and understand what's going on and know that you might need to make major changes to your implementation.

Comment: That being said, given the documentation for the query payload optimization, it sounds like this was an intentional change and not a "bug" so I wouldn't expect it to ever be "fixed" because it seems like this is the intentional behavior now. As the documentation says, users accessing the object through the FactHandle will need to update their code to set it manually.